# Preferred way to select components - by similar ids or by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm in a dilemma, academically speaking. I can't decide between two approaches to selecting a bunch of DIVs - both work perfectly so it's really a matter of niceness of code. What would be the schoolbook example to be preferred? Why the one and not the other?

```
var bunch_1 = $("[id$=viltersten]");
var bunch_2 = $(".konrad");
```

The only difference I can think of is that by-class-selection is more robust in case we add other DIVs, because the taxonomy doesn't need to be respected. On the other hand, that requires the programmer to remember to classify the newly added DIV. Plus, in this particular case, the id suffix is **considerably** specific and the collision may be assumed never to happen.

Putting these consideration aside, which would be a preferred approach and why?

Comment: by far: `.class` (faster, more readable ... )

Comment: @Utopik I'm **very** prone to agree that it's more readable, now that I think of it. The speed difference issue - is it considerable or just a slight concern? Also - please put your thought as a reply, not a comment, so I can check it green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `.class` because :

- **it is the goal of a class**
- it is more readable
- it is faster (Ok, we don't care, there is no significant difference)
- no ID collision possible

Exemple :

```
<div class='konrad' data-id="15">content</div>
<div class='konrad' data-id="51">content</div>
```

```
$('.konrad').each( function() {
  console.log( $(this).data("id") ); // will print 15, then 51
});

// edit one element : here, an ID might be better
$('.konrad[data-id="51"]').text('content changed');
```

This code is very easy to read, easy to maintain, and HTML is easy to generate (i.e in a loop).

You can use ID **and** classes for each item, but if you need to select them all, I advise you to use class selector.

Same thought for CSS uses.